# How to write select query with multiple records fetched in Mysql Trigger?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables product_history having 3 columns

1. id
2. product_id
3. admin_id

And another table(product_data) is to store data like..

1. admin name
2. product name
3. product description
4. product number .... etc.

Now I want to write a Mysql Trigger like.
when record insert in product_history table I need to fetch all products and admin related information from product table and admin table and insert those records in product_data table.

How can I do this?

Basically I want to use select query with in Trigger body, but that select query can return multiple records. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can retrive this information without need to insert data in another table, you can have: **admin_id** in your **product_data** table (and your admin_name, but would be redundat).

With your current idea, in your current **product_data** you should have a **product_id** field to related with your other table.

Comment: but I knowingly need to insert that records in product_data table. Its my requirement.